# CSS Horizontal Menu

Tags: css

I want to have a menu that consists of 6 tabs, 4 of which are visible at any given point.  I'd like to use javascript to control the viewport of this div tag.  I currently have 4 tabs showing, but I don't see the other tabs off to the right side beyond the viewport (I should see them given the width of the tab)... is `overflow:hidden` not what I should be doing?

```
#sub-navigation .tabs {
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
width: 808px;
left: 34px;
}
```

Comment: I am a little unclear. Are you scrolling the tabs left and right with javascript to see the hidden ones? Otherwise, overflow hidden would hide what is not being displayed inside 808px.

Comment: Going to need to see more than that to diagnose this.

Comment: Need a little more information about the markup and CSS around it. Also not sure why you mean...you say you only want to show 4, but you have a problem now that you can only see 4?

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` will hide any content outside of the container's area. If you want content outside of the container's area to be visible you should use `overflow: visible`.

It's hard to tell from your question exactly what it is you're trying to do though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're combining the tabs with their parent. By your question I would have expected something like this:

```
<ul> // position:absolute; width:808px;
  <li></li> // float:left; width:?; margin:?;
</ul>
```